# Apple Photos app on Mac OS Catalina - Not enough space to migrate photos library even with tonnes of space

Tags: catalina, photos.app

My Mac mini has a 1 tb ssd, and after updating it to Catalina and trying to open the Photos Library the Photos app starts to do a conversion and then fails. The photos library is 122 gb in size and there is over 4x that much space left on the disk (500 gb free space, apparently, although disk utility and finder show different numbers).  And yet we get this warning and the photo library conversion fails out with no option to repair or retry.

This photos library has been around since iPhoto days and has been migrated whenever the bright sparks at Apple decided (about annually) that everything they knew last year about photo library formats was wrong, and needed a total redo.

Opening up the contents we see various levels of content going back to about 2009.

[image: failure]

How can I get this photo library to open and not lose all the work that went into building it?

I can recover jpg images from inside the folder manually but that means file names, titles, and folders that Photos had would all be lost.

The even brighter sparks inside apple decided to Not Even Be Able to Not Lie To You about disk space also, so there's different values read in various places...   Disk Utility says 72 gb free, Macintosh HD info in finder says 400 gb free.  Get it together apple.

[image]

After showing the container folder and deleting local snapshots (which are totally invisible to the disk utility, and have to be removed with tmutil), it now shows 404 gb Free in the container disk, but still will not migrate the photos library...

[image: 403 gb free]

diskutil output:

```
> diskutil ap list
 
APFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 E0937E11-D6FC-4270-9BD2-378DF930BF07
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk1
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      999995129856 B (1000.0 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   605708021760 B (605.7 GB) (60.6% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       394287108096 B (394.3 GB) (39.4% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2 37BF024B-1EDE-4BE7-9EEE-676F7B920017
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
    |   Size:                       999995129856 B (1000.0 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s1 D2B2BC04-22A7-417C-AAFD-14038DFD70CB
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (Data)
    |   Name:                      Macintosh HD - Data (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Data
    |   Capacity Consumed:         580781342720 B (580.8 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s2 74F2074D-21F3-45F3-9C7B-B88E81126187
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s2 (System)
    |   Name:                      Macintosh HD (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /
    |   Capacity Consumed:         11225669632 B (11.2 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s3 D120BC33-1CAB-4F50-8F6E-0B9456021AA8
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s3 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         81293312 B (81.3 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s4 ED6A2C53-2EA9-43A3-B40A-5E2033278164
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         525844480 B (525.8 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s5 D4824E11-62A6-4B36-BA60-A7EE5A56A4BD
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s5 (VM)
        Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /private/var/vm
        Capacity Consumed:         12885979136 B (12.9 GB)
        FileVault:                 No
```

Comment: Just for some information - photo library migration does NOT mean the entire format is changed, just that some stuff has changed. Adding a new edit mode would likely require a faster - but still present - migration.

Comment: As for the issue itself, first please confirm you actually have that much free space using Disk Utility instead of Finder. This screenshot is from a more recent version of macOS but you should still be able to observe the presence (or lack) of that free space by navigating to the Container Disk view (if not present click View > Show All Devices) https://i.imgur.com/l6xVQed.png

Comment: There's nothing wrong - that space is "purgeable" cloud-storage type space, or it's being used by a system snapshot (which is taken before OS updates to allow you to revert in case of error in upgrade). That being said, it can be clunky to work around this issue when it surfaces.

Can you run this command for me in the Terminal app: `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /` - do any results appear?

Comment: (To clarify: it is space that is taken, but the system will delete when needed. Sometimes this just doesn't happen correctly - Finder shows it as free for this reason, but Disk Utility shows the actual used space).

Comment: There are a tonne of snapshots.

Comment: After removing snapshots, disk utility shows 404 gb free but photos still won't repair. I gotta say this is a horrendous mis-feature of Catalina.   Apple has jumped the shark.

Comment: Might be obvious, but have you tried restarting since you did that?

Comment: Can you give the result of terminal command `diskutil ap list `?

Comment: It's a bit long. Adding it to the question.  394 gb free. This is a 112 gb photo library and surely 3x its actual size should be enough free space.

Comment: @WarrenP Yes that should be enough space